# Control iTunes from a cocoa application

Tags: cocoa, macos, itunes

I am developing a mac application that involves audio playback. 
I would like to pause other audio players when our playback starts.

how can I
1) detect that itunes is running
2) detect that itunes is currently playing
3) pause itunes
4) resume itunes when I am done

also:
5) Is the a way to pause other types of media playback as well? audio and video in the in the browser for example?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do that with the following code which is using ScriptingBridge:

```
#import "iTunes.h"
#import "Cocoa/Cocoa.h"

int main()
{
  iTunesApplication* iTunes = [SBApplication applicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.iTunes"];

  // check if iTunes is running (Q1)
  if ([iTunes isRunning])
  {
    // pause iTunes if it is currently playing (Q2 and Q3)
    if (iTunesEPlSPlaying == [iTunes playerState])
      [iTunes playpause];

    // do your stuff

    // start playing again (Q4)
    [iTunes playpause];
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The file `iTunes.h` is generated by running `sdef /Applications/iTunes.app | sdp -fh --basename iTunes` from a commandline. The error `unknown type name "tdta"` can be ignored.

You also need to add ScriptingBridge.framework to the linked frameworks.

Here is also a link to the [ScriptingBridge documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptingBridgeConcepts/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006104-CH1-DontLinkElementID_17).

Comment: what is iTunesEPlSPlaying? and is there a way to detect if audio is playing with swift?

Comment: what data type is playerState?

Answer (score 5):

> 1) detect that itunes is running

[NSRunningApplication](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSRunningApplication_Class/) or [Process Manager](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Reference/Process_Manager/).

> 2) detect that itunes is currently playing
>   3) pause itunes
>   4) resume itunes when I am done

[Scripting Bridge.](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/ScriptingAutomation/Reference/ScriptingBridgeFramework/)

> 5) Is the a way to pause other types of media playback as well?

That depends on the application.

> audio and video in the in the browser for example?

No.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe creating an AppleScript can solve the problem?

Check this out:

http://dougscripts.com/itunes/

or some command line scripts?:

http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20011108211802830